# Kubernetes ui not showing deployed services or deployyment

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Is there a way to get the kubernetes-dashboard to show deployments and services that were created using the kubectl command, or can it only show things created via its web ui?

Is there maybe a setting in the yaml file that I need to modify to make it visible to the web ui?  I am running a kubernetes(1.2.5) in googles container engine. I know that the backend used to support only RC, but that was fixed.

here is the yaml i use to create the service and deployment:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app-name
  labels:
    app: nginx
    role: api
    tier: backend
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
    name: http
  - port: 443
    name: https
  selector:
    app: nginx
    role: api
    tier: backend
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app-name
spec:
  replicas: 6
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
        role: api
        tier: backend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: survey-node
        image: gcr.io/project/app-name:v0.0.1
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 300m
            memory: 500Mi
```

and here is the deployment after creation:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "3"
  creationTimestamp: 2016-07-07T23:22:16Z
  generation: 9
  labels:
    app: app-name
    role: app
    tier: backend
  name: app-name
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "4403"
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/deployments/app-name
  uid: *********-***-****-****-************
spec:
  replicas: 14
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app-name
      role: app
      tier: backend
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 1
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: app-name
        role: app
        tier: backend
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: gcr.io/project-name/app-name:v0.0.1
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: app-name
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 300m
            memory: 500Mi
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      nodeSelector:
        cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool: beef
      restartPolicy: Always
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
status:
  availableReplicas: 14
  observedGeneration: 9
  replicas: 14
  updatedReplicas: 14
```

Comment: Or should i ask this question over at the kubernetes github repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you upgrade your cluster to version 1.3 you'll automatically have new Dashboard which shows deployments and services.

Comment: cool, I'll have to wait for google to update their clusters, currently at 1.25